# point domain and subdomain to different folders using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two folders in my webroot (main & demo). I have pointed the website using .htacess to main folder. Ie, when i call www.domain.com then it will display content from main folder. Now i have made a subdomain www.demo.domain.com. When i access the subdomain, i am getting a 404 Not Found Error. What i really want is, when www.domain.com is called it should access contents in main folder & when i call www.demo.domain.com it should access the contents from demo folder. Below is the htacess file i have written. Sorry, i dont really know much about htacess.

```
RewriteEngine on
#if a match for asset is found, do nothing
RewriteRule ^main/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} main/
RewriteRule ^main/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !main/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+main/
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+demo/
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)$ http://demo.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(main|demo)/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demo\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [L]
```